# How to get the list of private videos from my channel using Dailymotion API

Tags: dailymotion-api

We are creating an application for educators where teachers can upload their videos on Dailymotion and student can watch the uploaded videos by teachers.

The uploaded videos can only be watch by our application no private link will be shared.
The Dailymotion player will be used for video purpose embed.

To create this application I need to get the list of private videos from my channel.
I tried the Dailymotion API explorer but didn't get any solution.

This is how I am getting the trending video lists :
"https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_360_url,title&1&limit=30&tags=trending"

Like this, I want to get a list of private videos.

Please help me with this tell me is it possible or not.

Thanks to read and feedback if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your private videos by adding the [`private`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#video-private-filter) filter to your query.

API call exmaple:
`https://api.dailymotion.com/user/<your_channel_id>/videos?fields=description,id,thumbnail_360_url,title,private&limit=30&private=true`

Reminder, you need to be [authenticated](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#authentication) to the API to retrieve private videos

Comment: I tried the above link with my channel id but get no response even though I have two videos private.

https://ibb.co/ckpsW6G

Comment: Two possibilities, either you are performing your  API call without authentication or you are authenticated with a user who is not the owner of this channel

Comment: Do you have any examples How can I perform that? Where I can send my authentication?

Comment: sorry to msg in the thread but It's urgent for me to get the solution ASAP.
please, anyone, reply if you know something about it.

Comment: Everything is explained in the link provided in the answer. Basically, you need to generate a token using the Oauth2 protocol and use it in your queries. If you are not too familiar with this, we have SDKs(https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks/) that ease the authentication process